# How do I print const char?

Tags: c++, char, constants, cout, p-lang

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int age = 20;
    const char* pDept = "electronics";
    cout << age << " " << pDept;
}
```

The above code is normal.

Why shouldn't I use `cout << *pDept` instead of `cout << pDept` above?

Comment: _"Why shouldn't I use cout << *pDept instead of cout << pDept above?"_ because that would print only the 1st character of the literal.

Comment: a `const char *` string is an array of `char`  (`null` terminated). By dereferencing, you will get the first `char`

Comment: In some circumstances (like printing) C++ treats `char*` as a special case meaning a nul terminated string. But if you said `*pDept` then you should have `char` and that means a **single** character, in your case that would print just `e`.

Comment: *"Why shouldn't I use cout << *pDept..."* You could use that. Who said you shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are legal in C++. Which one to use depends on what you want to print.

In your case, `pDept` is a pointer that points to a `char` in memory. It also can be used as a `char[]` terminated with `\0`. So `std::cout << pDept;` prints the string the pointer is pointing to.

`*pDept` is the content that `pDept` points to, which is the first character of the string. So `std::cout << *pDept;` prints the first character only.